# Find the limit of a sequence and show that it is Cauchy

Tags: limits, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{c_j : j \ge 1\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers and $s_m = \sum_{j=1}^m c_j$ be a sequence of partial sums. Suppose $s_m \le k $ for all $m \ge 1$. What is $\lim_{m \to \infty} s_m$? Show that this is a Cauchy sequence.

I think I know how to show that it is Cauchy pretty easily. From the way it is defined, the sequence has to be strictly increasing and it is bounded, which quickly gives the Cauchy property.

However, I'm not sure I see how to show what the limit actually is. My immediate guess would be that it is $k$, but that's just a hunch.... I feel like I might need to do something with subsequences, but that's also just a feeling.

Comment: There's no way to find the limit as the problem is posed. If $k$ was the supremum of the $s_m$ then the limit would be equal to $k$.

Comment: If $c_j =2^{-j}$ then $s_m leq 100$  but it converges to $1$ (anything greater than $1$ instead of $100$ works). The limit is the supremum, but we can't say anything else without more hypothesis